# How To include assembly in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have created a usercontrol and passed it's assembly in second usercontrol. I have written correct namespace in Xaml File but still it is saying that `CLR clr-namespace is not defined in assembly` How to solve this Problem? Can anyone help me. My Code is:

**First UserControl XAML File:**

`<xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesktopApplication.Roles"> 
<UserControl.Resources> <local:StringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>`

**Second UserControl .CS File:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace DesktopApplication.Admin_Roles
{


    public partial classCategoryTab : UserControl
    {

        public CategoryTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }


    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public bool isactive { get; set; }
    }
    public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((string)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((Color)value).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

UserControl1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:sample="clr-namespace:Sample"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300">
        <UserControl.Resources>
        <sample:StringToColorConverter x:Key="ddd"></sample:StringToColorConverter>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>            
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl2:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Sample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public bool isactive { get; set; }
    }
    public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((string)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((Color)value).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have moved Data & StringToColorConverter to Sample namespace then everything works fine after "compiling".

And also there is namespace mismatch in your code:

correct:

```
<xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesktopApplication.Admin_Roles"> <UserControl.Resources>
```

wrong:

```
<xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesktopApplication.Roles"> <UserControl.Resources>
```